# How to insert figures in two columns?

Tags: floats, two-column

In my case the figure disappears.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw circle (1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Figure in two column}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want a figure with the width of a single column, and don't need it to float, you can also use the `\begin{figure}[H]` option of the `float` package to place it explicitly:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{1}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw circle (1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Figure in two column}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: single column figure]

Comment: how could I insert the same figure but along the space of the two column?

Answer (score 10):

You should get a warning, printed to the `.log` file:

> Package multicol Warning: Floats and marginpars not allowed inside `multicols' 
>   environment!.

However, you could use `figure*`. See section *2.4 Floats inside a multicols environment* in the multicol documentation.

> Within the multicols environment the usual star 
>   float commands are available but their function is
>   somewhat different as in the twocolumn mode of standard LaTeX.
>   Starred floats, e.g., figure*, denote page wide 
>   floats that are handled in a similar fashion as normal 
>   floats outside the multicols environment. However, they
>   will never show up on the page
>   where they are encountered.